How long must a sample last in a molecular dynamics run for it to be considered non-labile?
So I have a few unusual molecules and I wanted to know whether or not they are kinetically stable (non-labile) across a certain range of temperatures. The methods for synthesizing these molecules isn't known, for they are novel and a product of engineering and imagination.
I'm trying to theoretically argue for the kinetic (or in-)stability of these molecules via Molecular Dynamics runs. The idea is that if the simulation box containing a sample of my molecules can go at least a threshold time $\tau$ without decomposing or spontaneously reacting in anyway, then I can have, say $95\%$ confidence that the sample is kinetically stable for the specific conditions of pressure, temperature, density and/or concentration of the simulation run.
I would still have to do a lot of MD runs for several distinct conditions but at least I would have a good measure stick against which to judge all of them.
So my question is: Is there a way to systematically calculate $\tau$?

Unfortunately, there is no good answer to this question. This is because molecular dynamics is not the tool for verifying kinetic stability. And that is because the timescales accessible to sampling with molecular dynamics, especially for reactive events that interest you, are very short compared to the timescales which we observe as humans and experimentalists. In general, if some reaction happens in a molecular dynamics simulation, that does not mean the reaction will occur in reality, but the reaction is kinetically plausible. However, if a reaction is not seen in a molecular dynamics simulation, that does not mean that the reaction is implausible. In other words, molecular dynamics is a very weak test of stability that should not be over-interpreted.
So if someone runs a molecular dynamics simulation for, say, a nanosecond and nothing happens, that does not mean that the simulated structure is stable even on the order of a microsecond, at the temperature simulated. So if you really want to see if something is stable for a time $\tau$, you will need to run the molecular dynamics for that timescale. Typical $\tau$ of interest to humans range from seconds to years and are not feasible to simulate.
Here are some things you could try instead:

Run molecular dynamics at strongly elevated temperatures in hopes of seeing some, any reaction happening. This will need to be interpreted cautiously given the sampling problem above.
Attempt a few nudged elastic band calculations along plausible decomposition pathways. This can estimate activation barriers for those directions, but the list will not be exhaustive, and the choice of products can strongly influence the results.
Use enhanced-sampling approaches, such as metadynamics, to drive reactions within molecular dynamics, and then subsequently evaluate how plausible the reactions are. With enhanced sampling, it should be possible to drive a simulation more or less until something breaks or reacts, but whether that reaction is physical becomes the real question.
Resort to a reaction network approach, see for example https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2021/sc/d0sc05647b


I want to add to this, MD showing a breakdown of molecules on the other hand is a good indication its not only kinetically unstable but also short lived.
